# Reactivity order of Shiny UI elements

Tags: r, shiny

Using an action button, I would like to load some preset values into the UI elements of my shiny app and then trigger an output from the updated UI's. In the app below there are two buttons. `Print` will print whatever is in input$txt to the output. The `preset` button should update the UI element with the preset value and subsequently print this value to the output. The desired functionality is equivalent to pressing `preset` followed by `print`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('txt','Text',value = ''),
      actionButton('print','Print'),
      actionButton('preset','preset')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("outText")
    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(text='')

  observeEvent(input$print,{
    values$text <- input$txt
  })
  observeEvent(input$preset,{
    presetVal <-'Some preset value'
    session$sendInputMessage('txt', list(value = presetVal))
  })

  output$outText <- renderPrint({
    print(values$text)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So why not just do this?

```
  observeEvent(input$preset,{
    presetVal <-'Some preset value'
    session$sendInputMessage('txt', list(value = presetVal))
    values$text <- presetVal
  })
```

My app has alot of dynamic UI elements and also modular filters the result of which is a filtered data frame which is used in the output. So in order to get the correct filtered data frame, the UI elements themselves need to be refreshed before creating the output. If that makes sense. So is it possible to mimic the action of pressing `preset` followed by `print`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, if you let all the UI elements depend on input$preset, they all get refreshed once `preset` is pressed.

library(shiny)

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput('txt','Text',value = ''),
      actionButton('print','Print'),
      actionButton('preset','preset'),
      uiOutput('myOutput')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("outText")
    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # default counter just for demonstration of dependency on preset button
  default <<- 0

  output$myOutput <- renderUI({

    input$preset # to introduce dependency on preset button

    default <<- default + 1

    textInput('myText', '', value = default)
  })

  values <- reactiveValues(text='')

  observeEvent(input$print,{
    values$text <- input$txt
  })
  observeEvent(input$preset,{
    presetVal <-'Some preset value'
    session$sendInputMessage('txt', list(value = presetVal))
    values$text <- presetVal
  })

  output$outText <- renderPrint({
    print(values$text)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```